# Edit data in a table that has relationship with another in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Agenda" id="formedit">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-light">
                <h5 class="modal-title">edit schedule</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-danger"></div>

                <input hidden asp-for="Id" id="id" class="form-control"/>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Guid" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Status" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="DateRegister" />
                <input hidden asp-for="UserID" id="userId" class="form-control" />


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-7">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
                                <select id="driver2" asp-for="DriverID" class="input100" asp-items="ViewBag.Driver">
                                    <option selected>Select Driver</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
                            <select id="Destination" class="input100" asp-items="ViewBag.Location">
                                <option selected>Select Destination</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
                            <textarea placeholder="Reason" id="DestinationObservation" class="border-0 input100"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class=" btn-lg btn btn-link float-right" onclick="AddMaintenance()">Add</button>

                    </div>

                    <div id="displaydestinations" class="predefinedsize  overflow-auto col-5">
                        <partial name="_PartialPoints" />
                    </div>

                    <hr />

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div>
                        <input id="buttonSend" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

when I click on:
 `<button type="button" class=" btn-lg btn btn-link float-right" onclick="AddMaintenance()">Add</button>`

a javascript function is called adding the select data with id ="Destination" and from the textarea to a div with id="displaydestinations"

The _PartialPoints file is defined as follows:

```
@model VehicleManagerSystem.Models.Reservation

@foreach (var item in Model.Stoppoints)
{
    <div class=" border border-1 card list_divs p-3" id="@item.IdLocalizacao">
        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Id" id="idpontos" class="form-control" />
        <input hidden asp-for="@item.IdReservation" class="form-control" />
        <input hidden asp-for="@item.Guid" id="guid-reserva" class="form-control" />

        <select required asp-for="@item.Location.Id" class="list_destinos font-weight-bold teste-select input100" asp-items="ViewBag.Location2"></select>

        <textarea asp-for="@item.Motivo" id="DestinoObservacao" value="@item.Motivo" class="list_observacoes border-0 input100"></textarea>

        <p class="text-primary" style="font-size: 15px;">@Model.DataInicio - @Model.DataFim</p>

        <button onclick="DeleteDestination(@item.Id, @Model.Id)" class=" btn btn-outline-danger" value="@item.Id" type="button">Remove</button>

    </div>
}
```

which generates me the following PartialView (attached image):

[image: attached image]

When I click on input:
`<input id="buttonSend" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />`

A javascript function is called capturing all the form data and inserting it into an object named formData. Subsequently, the data contained in FormData is sent to a C# .NET controller using ajax:

```
var Toast;
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            url: "/agend/edit/{id?}",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.code === 1) {
                    new swal
                        ({
                            text: "Reservation updated successfully!",
                            icon: "success",
                        }).then(function () {
                            window.location = `@Url.Action("Index", "Agend")`
                        });
                }


            },
            error: function (err) {
                swal
                    ({
                        text: 'Failed to change reservation',
                        type: 'error',
                        timeout: 2500,
                        progressBar: true
                    });
            }
        });
```

Controller Edit content in C# responsible for updating the data sent in the database:

```
[Route("edit/{id?}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Reserv reserv)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Entry(reserv).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Json(new
                {
                    Code = 1,
                    Message = "save.",
                    ClassAlert = "success",
                    Timer = 2500
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return Json(new
                {
                    Code = 0,
                    Message = "Erro: " + e.Message,
                    ClassAlert = "error",
                    Timer = 2500
                });
            }
        }
```

All the data needed to update is normally arriving at the controller's Reserv object. And I am managing to update normally the fields of type hidden and the field:

```
<select id="driver2" asp-for="DriverID" class="input100" asp-items="ViewBag.Driver">
       <option selected>Select Driver</option>
 </select>
```

However, the fields contained in:

```
<div id="displaydestinations" class="predefinedsize  overflow-auto col-5">
       <partial name="_PartialPoints" />
 </div>
```

they are not saved and neither do they show errors, it just returns a success message but does not change anything.

Note: Fields that are being saved correctly go to a table called reserv, while data from the div id="displaydestination" that is not being saved goes to a different table called breakpoints. The tables have a relationship with each other.

I hope that all submitted fields are updated in the database. I tried to do it the same way I do for forms that only go to a single table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through a similar problem recently. Probably, the entity framework is unable to map its related table and therefore cannot update the field and does not return an error
Try this on your MODEL:

```
public virtual ICollection<Points> Points{ get; set; }
```